# Complete minors of the grid graphs $\mathbb{Z}^n$

Tags: graph-theory, graph-minors, hadwiger-conjecture

Let $n>1$ be an integer. We say that two points $(x_1,\ldots,x_n),(y_1,\ldots,y_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ are a member of the edge set $E_n$ if and only if $$\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-y_i| = 1.$$

**Question.** Given an integer $n>1$, is there a maximal integer $m(n)$ such that the complete graph $K_{m(n)}$ is a [minor](https://dominiczypen.wordpress.com/2018/06/02/a-definition-of-minor-in-graph-theory/) of $(\mathbb{Z}^n, E_n)$? If yes, it would also be nice to know an explicit formula for $m(n)$.

**Remark.** I believe that for $n=2$ there is such a maximal integer, and $m(2) \in \{3,4\}$. I am fairly certain that $m(2) >4$ would allow to construct a counterexample to the [4-color theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem).)

**Edit.** In the comment section, Wojowu shows that $m(2)=4$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure $m(2)=4$ (consider minor given by sets $\{(1,1)\},\{(0,0),(0,1),(0,2)\},\{(1,0),(2,0),(2,1)\},\{(1,2),(2,2)\}$) and $m(n)$ is infinite for $n>2$ (by some construction similar to the fact any graph can be embedded in $\mathbb R^3$ without intersections). I will let someone else write up the details.

Comment: Thanks for your argument! Will put it into the problem statement as remark

Comment: "$m(2)>2$  would allow to construct a counterexample to the $4$-color theorem" -- you meant $m(2)>4$, of course.

Comment: Right Adam - will correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either I am missing something or for $n>2$ you have $m(n)=\infty$. It is enough to show this for $n=3$. Choose any $m$ and a set of edges in $E_3$ which is the union of the following three sets:

- $\{(i,j,0),(i,j+1,0)\}\mbox{ such that } 1\leq i\leq m\mbox{ and } 1\leq j < m$
- $\{(i,j,1),(i+1,j,1)\}\mbox{ such that } 1\leq i < m\mbox{ and } 1\leq j\leq m$
- $\{(i,i,0),(i,i,1)\}\mbox{ such that } 1\leq i\leq m$

Then the subgraph determined by these edges has $m$ connected components and any two of them are "connected" to each other in your sense.

Comment: Is the infinite case directly realizable, in that $K_\omega$ is a minor of $\mathbb{Z}^3$?

Comment: @Yes, just take $m=\infty$ and $i,j<m$